# How to allow a skip or goto at any time during a context in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip

I am trying to make an enable alarm function in my pbx, so far I have this context going which works. I would like to allow a number or # being pressed at any time during the countdown (playtones) to skip to the Alarm is now armed moment (or maybe the other extension, either way works).

The issue I am facing is that Read or WaitExten only works for the defined time, but I would like to continue the dialplan and allow the button press at any time in the channel.

```
exten => s,1,NoOp(enable alarm)
        same => n,Set(DB(alarm/status)=Enabled)
        same => n,Wait(1)
        same => n,Answer()
        same => n,Playback(customsounds/arming-in-45-seconds)
        same => n,Playtones(825/150,0/1550)
        same => n,Wait(10)
        same => n,Playtones(825/150,0/1000)
        same => n,Wait(10)
        same => n,Playtones(825/150,0/510)
        same => n,Wait(10)
        same => n,Playtones(825/150,0/100)
        same => n,Wait(5)
        same => n,Playtones(825/1500)
        same => n,Wait(3)
        same => n,StopPlaytones()
        same => n,Playback(customsounds/the-alarm-is-now-armed)
        same => n,NoOp(do shell exec here)
        same => n,HangUp()

exten => 1,1,NoOp(skipped countdown)
        same => n,Playback(customsounds/the-alarm-is-now-armed)
        same => n,NoOp(do shell exec here)
        same => n,HangUp()
```

Comment: features.conf and its applicationmap was a suggestion earlier by a user (who deleted his comment) but is not a possibility since it only works with a caller and a callee

Answer (score 0):

You may build up your context using Asterisks Read() dialplan application instead of Wait(). The Read() application does provide a timeout parameter which you can set to your specific value. If a user presses # during the Read(), the reading will be interrupted and you can continue. Otherwise the reading will be aborted after the passed timeout. To play your tones in background you can use the filename parameter of the Read() application which can be used to play some audiofiles in the background while waiting for an DTMF input.

In this case a solution may look like this:

```
exten => s,1,NoOp(enable alarm)
    same => n,Set(DB(alarm/status)=Enabled)
    same => n,Wait(1)
    same => n,Answer()
    same => n,Playback(customsounds/arming-in-45-seconds)
    same => n,Read(get,customsounds/waitingsound,,,,45)
    same => n,Playback(customsounds/the-alarm-is-now-armed)
    same => n,NoOp(do shell exec here)
    same => n,HangUp()
```

Maybe the syntax is not 100% correct but it should work like that in your case. You can read more about the Read() application here: http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/applikationen-read.html

Or here: https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-cmd-read/